# How do I make webpack also load preload.js when starting a dev server using electron-forge

Tags: webpack, electron, electron-forge

### Problem

For my Electron app created with `npx create-electron-app <appname> --template=typescript-webpack` the user needs to be able to open a new BrowserWindow instance (not the one you create with `window.open()`) on click of a button.

Since the initiative to open a new Window is coming from the frontend/renderer of the app, I have to use the ipcRenderer in order send a message to the main process in which then I can listen for the message in order to open a new BrowserWindow.

However I fail at telling webpack to also bundle the the required preload.js along with index.js, when starting the app via `yarn electron-forge start`.
The .webpack folder structure should look like this:

```
main
  index.js (main)
  preload.js
renderer
  main_window
    index.html
    index.js (renderer)
  ...
```

**But the preload.js is missing which leads to an error in the console and the button not working.**

When I manually copy the preload.js to the correct place (.webpack/main) after starting the devserver everything works which is nice to see, however it's not a solution.
Pretty sure something is wrong in my webpack configurations.

### Setup

The original index.ts and preload.js sit next to each other in the `src` folder

I'm a complete newbie when it comes to webpack or other comparable services so I have no idea what's wrong in my automatically generated webpack configurations. This is how they look like:

**webpack.main.config.js**

```
module.exports = {
  entry: "./src/index.ts",
  module: {
    rules: require("./webpack.rules"),
  },
  resolve: {
    extensions: [".js", ".ts", ".jsx", ".tsx", ".css", ".json"],
  },
};
```

**webpack.renderer.config.js**

```
const rules = require("./webpack.rules");
const plugins = require("./webpack.plugins");

rules.push({
  test: /\.css$/,
  use: [
    { loader: "style-loader" },
    { loader: "css-loader" },
    { loader: "postcss-loader" },
  ],
});

module.exports = {
  module: {
    rules,
  },
  plugins: plugins,
  resolve: {
    extensions: [".js", ".ts", ".jsx", ".tsx", ".css"],
  },
};
```

**webpack.plugins.js**

```
const ForkTsCheckerWebpackPlugin = require('fork-ts-checker-webpack-plugin');

module.exports = [new ForkTsCheckerWebpackPlugin()];
```

**webpack.rules.js**

```
module.exports = [
  {
    test: /native_modules\/.+\.node$/,
    use: 'node-loader',
  },
  {
    test: /\.(m?js|node)$/,
    parser: { amd: false },
    use: {
      loader: '@vercel/webpack-asset-relocator-loader',
      options: {
        outputAssetBase: 'native_modules',
      },
    },
  },
  {
    test: /\.tsx?$/,
    exclude: /(node_modules|\.webpack)/,
    use: {
      loader: 'ts-loader',
      options: {
        transpileOnly: true,
      },
    },
  },
];
```

If needed I can provide the source code for index.ts and preload.js and the file calling the method from the renderer process. I'm pretty sure though they're not the issue, since everything works, when I manually inject the preload.js into .webpack/main after starting.

Answer (score 1):

you can use the magic global variables which webpack and electron forge provides
read more about this at [magic global variables](https://www.electronforge.io/config/plugins/webpack#:%7E:text=These%20point%20to%20the%20paths%20for%20your%20renderer%20entry%20point%20and%20your%20preload%20script%20path%2C%20respectively.%20In%20the%20case%20of%20the%20main_window%20entry%20point%20in%20the%20earlier%20example%2C%20the%20global%20variables%20will%20be%20named%20MAIN_WINDOW_WEBPACK_ENTRY%20and%20MAIN_WINDOW_PRELOAD_WEBPACK_ENTRY)

hope below code help you:

for creating a browser window
and the `preload : MAIN_WINDOW_PRELOAD_WEBPACK_ENTRY` property will help to bundle preload.js to pack with other render scripts
`const mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({ width: 1000, height: 900, webPreferences:{ preload : MAIN_WINDOW_PRELOAD_WEBPACK_ENTRY, } });`

for loading the index.html of the app.

```
mainWindow.loadURL(MAIN_WINDOW_WEBPACK_ENTRY);
```

Comment: if this not resolve what you have asked please enlighten me little.

Comment: Thanks a lot, this got me on the track how this could possibly be solved.
In my package.json now I have added a "preload" property with the following entry points:
`
{
  "html": ".src/index.html",
  "js:": "./src/preload.js",
  "name": "main_window"
}
`
I'v also create a webpack.preload.config.js with the following entry property:
`"./src/preaload.js"`
And in index.ts I have 
`
new BrowserWindow({
  width: 1366,
  height: 768,
  backgroundColor: "#121212",
  webPreferences: {preload: MAIN_WINDOW_PRELOAD_WEBPACK_ENTRY,},
});
`
Still doesn't create the preload.js :/

Comment: i am not aware about the "webpack.preload.config.js" other things seems right to me, please check this repository of mine: https://github.com/anirudhsanthosh/shopper,
am using electron-forge with react and webpack but unfortunately no Ts

Comment: Thank you for your time. I've switched to another template using vite to avoid having to use webpack. Unfortunately I've deleted my old code for good, but from what I've gathered taking a look at your repo, I think what I was missing is adding the preload file to the forge configs the way you do it. So if anybody ever stumbles upon this exact problem -> give that a try.

Comment:  thannks man

Answer (score 1):

For future reference, in total, it looks like you might need to do two things in order to get the preload script to work:

1. Use [global variables](https://www.electronforge.io/config/plugins/webpack#project-setup) in the index.ts file, just as Anirudh suggested:

```js
// stuff...

// specifically for typescript: 
// the first declare should have been automatically generated
declare const MAIN_WINDOW_WEBPACK_ENTRY: string;
declare const MAIN_WINDOW_PRELOAD_WEBPACK_ENTRY: string; // add this

// other stuff...

const createWindow = (): void => {
  // Create the browser window.
  const mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({
    height: 600,
    width: 800,
    webPreferences: {
      preload: MAIN_WINDOW_PRELOAD_WEBPACK_ENTRY, // change this
    },
  });
  // and all the other things in index.ts.
}
```

2. After that, you might also need to change your package.json, just as Clemens suggested. This took a little bit more research, but the documentation for the webpack plugin can be found [here](https://js.electronforge.io/plugin/webpack/interfaces/webpackpluginconfig), wherein all the variables can be manipulated via the package.json entry for `config > forge > plugins`. Thus, the critical part there should look something like this:

```json
        [
          "@electron-forge/plugin-webpack",
          {
            "mainConfig": "./webpack.main.config.js",
            "renderer": {
              "config": "./webpack.renderer.config.js",
              "entryPoints": [
                {
                  "html": "./src/index.html",
                  "js": "./src/renderer.ts",
                  "name": "main_window",

                  // -------------- change starts here --------------
                  "preload": {
                    "js": "./src/preload.ts" // or wherever your preload script is written
                  }
                  // --------------  change ends here  --------------
                }
              ]
            }
          }
        ]
```

I'm also a beginner at javascript, so I'm not entirely sure if it's correct. Hope it helps!